# Paperclip is not saving avatar to user with a form only via console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, paperclip

I am one of those sad people that cannot get Rails 3.2.6, Devise and Paperclip to play happiely together. I am using a normal HTML-form to testing to create a user and at the same time uploading an avatar. According to the log, all looks fine but the image is not uploaded to Amazon S3 and the image details is not saved to the user.

This is the output from Heroku logs directly after I submitted:

```
2012-08-16T20:29:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/api/v1/users" for 90.224.160.143 at 2012-08-16 20:29:16 +0000
2012-08-16T20:29:16+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as JSON
2012-08-16T20:29:16+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"email"=>"eee@eee.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"eee", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000060fa310 @original_filename="farmer.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"farmer.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20120816-2-1oz8ytm>>}
2012-08-16T20:29:16+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Saving attachments.
2012-08-16T20:29:16+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Saving attachments.
2012-08-16T20:29:16+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Saving attachments.
```

This is the attachment code that I use in the User model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
      :bucket => "appprofilepictures",
      :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"},
      :path => 'photos/:id/:style/:id.:extension'
```

This is the attr_accessible:

```
attr_accessible :avatar, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :authentication_token
```

This is my html form code:

```
<form name='profile' action='http://example.com/users' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="email" />
<input type="text" name="password" />
<input type="text" name="password_confirmation" />
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="file" name="avatar" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I can manually create a user using in Heroku console and THEN it uploads.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are missing a couple pieces from your `:has_attached_file` for uploading to S3. If I remember correctly, the last time I set this up, it wouldn't upload without these.

```
:url            => ':s3_alias_url',
:s3_host_alias  => "<your-bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com",
```

That solved my problem the last time I set up Paperclip with S3. Also check out the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) on what is required.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this but the strange thing is that I can upload (when I create a user) in the terminal/console.